# Getting TextView in Fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to get the `TextView` in `Fragment` `onCreateView()` but its return `null`.
Below is the code snippet.

```
     View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_repotee, container,    false);
     TextView tv = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewNamere);
     tv.setText(EmpDirectoryListingFragment.emp_name);
```

I am getting the tv value `null`. Below is the XML of layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="h2h.telenor.com.fragments.TAFListingFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:background="#006400">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e4e4e4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f1f1f1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOpen"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewNamere"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Muhamamd Faisal Shahzad"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewOpen"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/up_arrow"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewEmpDownHierarchy"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show the xml of `fragment_employee_repotee` layout

Comment: are your returning this view that you inflated or something else?

Comment: I am returning the fragment_employee_repotee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_repotee, container,    false);
 TextView tv = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewOpen);//since there is not textview in your layout with id R.id.textViewNamere
 tv.setText(EmpDirectoryListingFragment.emp_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your layout only have one line use textViewNamere:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewNamere"
```

This line create a id `R.id.textViewNamere`. But The id not corresponding with any view so that `view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewNamere)` alway return null but not show error here.

Comment: Got it. I just copied my code to next fragment and totally forget about id. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in `onViewCreated()` method instead of `onCreateView`. This method will return you the view object. Use it for the initialization of your textview. Also make sure you are referencing it by correct id that you defined in xml.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml `textViewNamere` is not defined. You used `textViewNamere` as a reference like `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewNamere"`. Your actual TextView id is `textViewOpen`. So cast your TextView like

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewOpen);
```